# Centos - PHP Strict Standards - dedicated log file

Tags: php, logging, strict

I have enabled log errors in php.ini to php_error.log but it's logging only errors, strict standards and warrnings are writen to apache error.log.
It's possible to save strict and warrning messages to dedicated file, f.eg. php_strict.log?
I was thinking about turn on syslog in php.ini and then via rsyslog :msg contains, but first if it's possible to write another file directly by php?

Comment: It is possible but you need to write your own http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: You should also change the value of the error_reporting directive in php.ini if you want strict standards written into the log